# Литература для Java с советами по оптимизации

Tags: java, книги

Посоветуйте литературу для Java с советами по оптимизации кода или ресурс. Можно на английском.

*Мне нужна литература с рекомендациями как писать нормальный код, как поступать в отдельных случаях,какой путь выбрать, я понимаю все преимущества и недостатки java (поэтому не надо поднимать этот вопрос).

Comment: Java код и оптимизация это примерно тоже самое что +30 тепла в Москве в декабре, хотите скорости перепишите на С\asm это самое лучшее что можно сделать.

Comment: > Java код и оптимизация это примерно тоже самое что +30 тепла в Москве в декабре, хотите скорости перепишите на С/asm это самое лучшее что можно сделать.

время идет а люди не меняются, - не понимают как устроена java и не пытаются разобратся. асемблерный код транслируется в инструкции которые выполняет процессор. Java код транслируется в код который выполняет JVM. Поэтому можно даже сказать что java это компилируемый скрипт язык. Обсирая скорость ее вы обсираете производительность JVM (писаных на С между прочим).  

p.s. уже молчу о том что есть платформенно зависимая JIT компиляция

Comment: @igumnov то есть вы считаете, что Java-программы нельзя оптимизировать?
То есть вы считаете, что переписать тот же код только на c/asm даст огромный прирост производительности (я конечно не о говорю сейчас о разработке игр, например, это отдельная тема). 

По поводу вопроса все зависит от того, что пишите. Полезно знать внутренности (как работают классы, которые вы используете) и алгоритмы.

Comment: @jmu
Ничего не имею против Java, это хорошее годное средство разработки, но делать на ней что-то что требует чрезвычайно высокой пиковой производительности и большого расхода памяти правда плохая идея.

@rasmisha
Можно конечно. Но нужно хорошо понимать что, зачем, почему и каким образом оптимизируется. Если переписать тот же код на С то как минимум можно сэкономить память которая требуется для поддержания работы JVM.

А вообще производительность Java = холивар. Поэтому покидаю тред.

Comment: 2 @igumnov: лучше хороший код на java, чем плохой на С/Асм. Мне кажется, это очевидно всем. А еще скажу вам то, что очевидно любому "заказчику", - лучше написать продукт на java чем на С/Асм. Дешевле, быстрее и обычно более качественно (потому что специалистов приемливого уровня больше) + поддерживать легче.

p.s. адекватный программист будет оптимизировать даже тот код, который никому не нужен. Даже если это бат(шел) скрипт, дял дома, для одноразовой задачи. Нет ничего плохого в том, что человек хочет развиватся и писать код лучше, совершенстуясь при этом

Comment: @jmu
С тем что выше P.S. согласен. По поводу P.S. то это весьма спорно в том случае если проект больших размеров. В такой ситуации лучше вообще игнорировать однократно выполняющийся код и сосредоточиться на профилировании критически важных петель которые работают в реальном времени. Хотя я в основном занимаюсь 3D рендерингом, поэтому не знаю как эти вопросы решаются в других областях где требуется производительность, вроде нагруженных серверов с базами или каких-то сложных научных расчетов.

Comment: В сферах, которые вы упомянули выше, java вообще не используется. На счет оптимизаций, - вы описали алг применимый для любого языка. 

Касательно искомого вопроса: я думаю автор имел в виду не только оптимизацию перфоманса. Для меня оптимизация кода в первую очередь это clean up и рефакторинг, структурирование с использованием шаблонов, докуметирование. Даже если со временем появляется необходимость оптимизация перфоманса то это делается обычно с минимальными изменениями (я работаю в сфере где от продуктов не требуют космических скоростей)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java Performance 1st Edition by Charlie Hunt and Binu John (ISBN-13:978-0137142521, ISBN-10: 0137142528)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137142528)

Answer (score 5):

По апдейту могу посоветовать 
[Effective Java 2nd Edition by Joshua Bloch ( ISBN-13: 860-1300201986, ISBN-10: 0321356683)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683), одна из моих любимых книг

Answer (score 4):

> Мне нужна литература с рекомендациями
> как писать нормальный код

Вот конкретный how to как писать оптимальный код: [Java Code Optimization](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/optimization.html)

Answer (score 2):

Java Puzzlers - Joshua Bloch. Сейчас читаю - очень интересно